# Merge upper and lower matrix in SAS

Tags: matrix, merge, sas

I have a distance matrix in 2 parts: 1 upper triangular matrix and one lower triangular matrix. These are different datasets. When trying to merge them with the merge statement, like following:

```
DATA matrix;
   MERGE lower upper;
   BY city;
RUN;
```

I just get the second matrix (upper) as output. 
I think the empty values from "upper" overwrite the numeric values from "lower".

Is there a way to conserve the numeric values in the lower part of the matrix so I get a full matrix?

Comment: We need a little more info on your data structure, whether this is SAS/IML, etc. Please try to provide a minimally reproducible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE will "MERGE" but not overwrite missing.   Update is different in other ways but I will leave that to your investigation.

```
data upper;
   input city $ x y z;
   cards;
abc . 2 3
def . . 5
ghi . . .
data lower;
   input city $ x y z;
   cards;
abc . . .
def 4 . .
ghi 5 6 .
   run;
data upandlow;
   update upper lower;
   by city;
   run;
```

Comment: That's a really clever solution! This is a great idea

Comment: You might find this mildly interesting.
http://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2013/BB/PharmaSUG-2013-BB10.pdf

Comment: I found that moderately interesting. Expectations: Exceeded

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple, yet elegant solution!